# Fourier transform and LTI filter and frequency response in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, fft

I'm new to Matlab for LTI signal processing and wondering if anyone can help with something that I'm sure is meant to be basic. I've spent hours and hours researching and obtaining background information and still cannot obtain a clear path to tackle these problems. So far, from scratch, I have generated a signal required and managed to use the fft function to produce the signal's DFT:

```
function x = fourier_rikki(A,t,O)

Fs = 1000;
t = 0:(1/Fs):1;

A = [0.5,0,0.5];
N = (length(A) - 1)/2;
x = zeros(size(t));
f1 = 85;
O1 = 2*pi*f1;

for k = 1:length(A)
x1 = x + A(k)*exp(1i*O1*t*(k-N-1));
end

f2 = 150;
O2 = 2*pi*f2;

for k = 1:length(A);
x2 = x + A(k)*exp(1i*O2*t*(k-N-1));
end

f3 = 330;
O3 = 2*pi*f3;

for k = 1:length(A);
x3 = x + A(k)*exp(1i*O3*t*(k-N-1));
end

signal = x1 + x2 + x3;

figure(1);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t, signal);
title('Signal x(t) in the Time Domain');
xlabel('Time (Seconds)');
ylabel('x(t)');

X = fft(signal);  %DFT of the signal

subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t, X);
title('Power Spectrum of Discrete Fourier Transform of x(t)');
xlabel('Time (Seconds)');
ylabel('Power');

f = linspace(0, 1000, length(X)); %?

subplot(3,1,3);
plot(f, abs(X));  %Only want the positive values
title('Spectral Frequency');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Power');

end
```

At this stage, I'm assuming this is correct for:

"Generate a signal with frequencies 85,150,330Hz using a sampling frequency of 1000Hz - plot 1seconds worth of the signal and its Discrete Fourier Transform."

The next step is to "Find the frequency response of an LTI system that filters out the higher and lower frequencies using the Fourier Transform". I'm stuck trying to create an LTI system that does that! I have to be left with the 150Hz signal, and I'm guessing I perform the filtering on the FFT, perhaps using conv.

My course is not a programming course - we are not assessed on our programming skills and I have minimal Matlab experience - basically we have been left to our own devices to struggle through, so any help would be greatly appreciated! I am sifting through tonnes of different examples and searching Matlab functions using 'help' etc, but since each one is different and does not have a break down of the variables used, explaining why certain parameters/values are chosen etc. it is just adding to the confusion.

Among many (many) others I have looked at:
http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/adst-spring2010/lectures/matlab/lecture1.html
http://gribblelab.org/scicomp/09_Signals_and_sampling.html  section 10.4 especially.
As well as Matlab Geeks examples and Mathworks Matlab function explanations.
I guess the worst that can happen is that nobody answers and I continue burning my eyeballs out until I manage to come up with something :) Thanks in advance.

I found this bandpass filter code as a Mathworks example, which is exactly what needs to be applied to my fft signal, but I don't understand the attenuation values Ast or the amount of ripple Ap.

```
n = 0:159;
x = cos(pi/8*n)+cos(pi/2*n)+sin(3*pi/4*n);

d = fdesign.bandpass('Fst1,Fp1,Fp2,Fst2,Ast1,Ap,Ast2',1/4,3/8,5/8,6/8,60,1,60);
Hd = design(d,'equiripple');

y = filter(Hd,x);
freq = 0:(2*pi)/length(x):pi;
xdft = fft(x);
ydft = fft(y);

plot(freq,abs(xdft(1:length(x)/2+1)));
hold on;
plot(freq,abs(ydft(1:length(x)/2+1)),'r','linewidth',2);
legend('Original Signal','Bandpass Signal');
```

Comment: It sounds like you're being asked to plot the frequency response of a 150 Hz notch filter. 

If you want to do the filtering in the frequency domain you could just zero out all the bins except for the two that contain + and - 150 Hz components. 

This is equivalent to multiplying (filtering) your original signal's FFT by a frequency vector that has ones in the bins corresponding to + and - 150 Hz and zeros everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for replying David, that's exactly what needs doing. I'm not sure how to set up a freq vector but will research. Also found a bandpass design: 
'n = 0:159;
x = cos(pi/8*n)+cos(pi/2*n)+sin(3*pi/4*n);
d =     fdesign.bandpass('Fst1,Fp1,Fp2,Fst2,Ast1,Ap,Ast2',1/4,3/8,5/8,6/8,60,1,60);
Hd = design(d,'equiripple');
y = filter(Hd,x);
freq = 0:(2*pi)/length(x):pi;
xdft = fft(x);
ydft = fft(y);
plot(freq,abs(xdft(1:length(x)/2+1)));
hold on;
plot(freq,abs(ydft(1:length(x)/2+1)),'r','linewidth',2);
legend('Original','Bandpass');' Although I don't understand the fdesign.bandpass inputs

Comment: Ast is your stop-band attenuation, Ap is your pass-band ripple. These are common design parameters for specifying filter requirements. I don't think you want to go this route though, it just complicates things.

Instead you should do the filtering in the frequency domain since you already have the DFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can use as a reference. I think I got the gist of what you were trying to do. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
clear all
close all

Fs = 1000;
t = 0:(1/Fs):1;
N = length(t);

% 85, 150, and 330 Hz converted to radian frequency
w1 = 2*pi*85;
w2 = 2*pi*150;
w3 = 2*pi*330;

% amplitudes
a1 = 1;
a2 = 1.5;
a3 = .75;

% construct time-domain signals
x1 = a1*cos(w1*t);
x2 = a2*cos(w2*t);
x3 = a3*cos(w3*t);

% superposition of 85, 150, and 330 Hz component signals
x = x1 + x2 + x3; 

figure
plot(t(1:100), x(1:100));
title('unfiltered time-domain signal, amplitude vs. time');
ylabel('amplitude');
xlabel('time (seconds)');

% compute discrete Fourier transform of time-domain signal
X = fft(x); 
Xmag = 20*log10(abs(X)); % magnitude spectrum
Xphase = 180*unwrap(angle(X))./pi; % phase spectrum (degrees)
w = 2*pi*(0:N-1)./N; % normalized radian frequency
f = w./(2*pi)*Fs; % radian frequency to Hz
k = 1:N; % bin indices 

% plot magnitude spectrum
figure
plot(f, Xmag)
title('frequency-domain signal, magnitude vs. frequency');
xlabel('frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('magnitude (dB)');

% frequency vector of the filter. attenuates undesired frequency components
% and keeps desired components. 
H = 1e-3*ones(1, length(k));
H(97:223) = 1;
H((end-223):(end-97)) = 1;

% plot magnitude spectrum of signal and filter
figure
plot(k, Xmag)
hold on
plot(k, 20*log10(H), 'r')
title('frequency-domain signal (blue) and filter (red), magnitude vs. bin index');
xlabel('bin index');
ylabel('magnitude (dB)');

% filtering in frequency domain is just multiplication
Y = X.*H;

% plot magnitude spectrum of filtered signal
figure
plot(f, 20*log10(abs(Y)))
title('filtered frequency-domain signal, magnitude vs. frequency');
xlabel('frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('magnitude (dB)');

% use inverse discrete Fourier transform to obtain the filtered time-domain
% signal. This signal is complex due to imperfect symmetry in the
% frequency-domain, however the imaginary components are nearly zero.
y = ifft(Y);

% plot overlay of filtered signal and desired signal
figure
plot(t(1:100), x(1:100), 'r')
hold on
plot(t(1:100), x2(1:100), 'linewidth', 2)
plot(t(1:100), real(y(1:100)), 'g')
title('input signal (red), desired signal (blue), signal extracted via filtering (green)');
ylabel('amplitude');
xlabel('time (seconds)');
```

Here is the end result...
[image]

Comment: The filter only looks flat-lined due to the linear scale, if you zoom in you'll see that it's not flat. Regarding your second question it looks like the text was cut off.

Comment: Wow. That's really cool - such a neat code! Thanks so much David, I understand almost 100% of it. Just a couple of questions: 1. If I remove the 20log10 multiplication everywhere (i.e don't convert to decibels), the magnitude spectrum of the signal and filter plot shows the filter as a flat line. But if I multiply just the filter component H by 20log10 again, when plotting, it shows up. I'm probably missing something but do you know why it does that? 2. Why does the initial frequency vector, H have to be multiplied by 1e-3? Thanks again, you've already helped beyond expectation!!

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now! And yes, I hadn't finished - sorry!